# PHP: Saving files with PHP to different root directory?

Tags: php, php4

OK when I save uploaded files with PHP via move_uploaded_file() I cannot use an absolute URL I have to use a relative one. My site has 2 root directories one for the http side and one for the https side: httpdocs and httpsdocs respectively. So if my script is on the https side how can I save the file to a location on the http side?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**
OK so it seems like I am using the wrong absolute path convention I am doing it like this:

```
$dir = 'https://www.mydomain.com/masonic_images/';
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['blue_image']['tmp_name'], $dir.$new_name);
```

Comment: Why can't you use an absolute path?

Comment: @Chad I get an error when I use an absolute path. "Warning: move_uploaded_file(): URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration." Is that something I can adjust in an .htaccess file?

Comment: Can you show the move_uploaded_file call? It sounds like you're putting a URL instead of a file path, that won't work.

Comment: That error seems to indicate that you're using a URL instead of a filesystem path.

Comment: @Chad I added the call above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the httpdocs and httpsdocs directories both located in the same parent folder? If so, just use a relative path for the second parameter in move_uploaded_file to place the file in the other root directory.

For example:

```
$uploaddir = '../httpdocs/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['myfile']['name']);
```

This code assumes that the uploading script is located in the httpsdocs root directory, and that you want to save the file into the httpdocs directory.

Comment: Thanks, I tried what you said and I got this error: "Warning: move_uploaded_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(../../httpdocs/masonic_images/41_red_391-1-l.jpg) is not within the allowed path(s)"

Comment: Your web server has PHP configured to block all file accesses outside the current site root. Unless you can turn the open_basedir restriction off, there is no way to place the images in the other directory.

Comment: @Jon is there a way to do that with .htaccess? Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The open_basedir directive can only be changed in httpd.conf or php.ini.

Comment: @Jon I can ask my host to change this, but first is there any negative or security holes that can open by changing? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Not really, if you're careful to validate any user input that might control which files are opened/created.

Answer (score 5):

[`move_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/move_uploaded_file) doesn't accept URLs for either parameter. The destination is an absolute path on your filesystem.

```
<?php
$dir = '/var/www/httpsdocs/'; // Adjust to your configuration
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['blue_image']['tmp_name'], $dir.$new_name);
```

As @[apphacker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748915/php-saving-files-with-php-to-different-root-directory/748936#748936) suggested. you can use [`realpath(__FILE__)`](http://php.net/realpath) to determine the absolute path to a file.

Comment: I updated with an example. Absolute paths start with "/". URLS have "[protocol]://".

Comment: Thank you very much I gave you a 1+up for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot use the absolute path because you don't know what the absolute path is, use PHP's realpath() to figure out what it is and then use it.

Answer (score 1):

Note that since you put uploaded files inside `httpdocs` it could be possible to upload a php file and execute arbitrary code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, the users aren't using this though this is for employees to upload product images.