# upload image out side site root directory

Tags: php

I want to upload image out side site root directory using php? can any one tell me that how I give path of directory out side root for image upload ????

Answer (score 1):

did you try using `move_uploaded_file`

```
$upload_dir = '/out_directory/';
$upload_file = $upload_dir . basename($_FILES['filename']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename'], $upload_file);
```

also look at this topic

[PHP: Saving files with PHP to different root directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748915/php-saving-files-with-php-to-different-root-directory)